# Merge performance changing dramatically from few rows to thousands

Tags: merge, sql-server-2012

I have this legacy Job that runs every 5 minutes (inside it has a SP that is doing a MERGE).

It ran perfectly for the last couple of years… But the issue started when the SOURCE for the MERGE changed from 1,000 rows to 200,000 rows…

Did anyone go through something similar? This job used to take at most 2 minutes… Now sometimes it takes 2,3 hours to run…

Below a screenshot of the execution plan for the biggest merge (the SP has in total has 4 merges…) I try to use the execution plan to troubleshoot, but it was misleading… As even though it says (relative to the batch)= 0% this is the portion of the code that takes 90% of the time.
[image: d]

Comment: Please show the merge code.  Likely culprit is an unconditional `when matched then update set`.

Comment: As usual to answer questions like these, you need to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies; you have been really helpful…

The Job (stored procedure), involves 9 tables, with 4 merges and lots of joins and updates after the merge…

(Publishing it all would be way too long).

Finally, I have narrowed down the issue to the complexity of the SP (overall is doing 4 merges, 9 joins, and updating 3 more tables in the end):

And it all depends on this:

declare @TableVariable as SF_OpportunityMerge

insert  @ TableVariable
select  (20 columns)
from    [Remote_Server].[Salesforce].[dbo].[Opportunity]
where   UpdateDate > @LastUpdateDate

When this select (which is the base for most of the merges), returns 10, 20 rows… The Job runs in seconds, when it returns half a million rows will take around 2 hours, and it makes perfect sense, there are no blockings, no indexes missing (the table variable has an index on opportunity)…

Inside the job, the @TableVariable is used several times (including the merges), so the more results I get, it exponentially increases its duration…

Answer (score 0):

If processing of 1000 rows takes 2 minutes thus processing of 200'000 rows should take (predicted linearly) 6-7 hours. Performance does not seem to change dramatically - it's just bad and nothing more. Dig into real issue: to process poor 1000 rows your sp works up to 2 minutes. What is it doing? How many indexes do you have on your tables? Are there any clustered indexes on guids? Any clustered views dependent on these tables? Triggers?